# DRF - nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have several models

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birthday = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    heigth = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sign = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=SIGNS_CHOICES, default='E')
    orientation = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=ORIENTATION_CHOICES, default='E')
    bodytype = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=BODYTYPE_CHOICES, default='E')
    education = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES, default='E')
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=RELIGION_CHOICES, default='E')
    smoking = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=SMOKING_CHOICES, default='E')
    alcohol = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=ALCOHOL_CHOICES, default='E')
    kids = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=KIDS_CHOICES, default='E')
    pets = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=KIDS_CHOICES, default='E')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longtitude = models.FloatField()

class ProfilePic(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profilePic = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/', default='Images/None/No-img.jpg')

class ProfileFields(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and several serizlizers

```
class ProfilePicSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfilePic
        fields = [
            'profilePic',
            'user',
        ]

class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'

class ProfileFieldsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfileFields
        fields = [
            'user',
            'title',
            'text',
            'order'
        ]
```

What I try to do is to create user serizlizer that will show profile, profilePic and profileFields

I do it like so

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(many=False)
    profilePic = ProfilePicSerializer(many=False)
    profile_fields = ProfileFieldsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

But I get error

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `profilePic` on serializer `UserSerializer`.The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.Original exception text was: &#39;User&#39; object has no attribute &#39;profilePic&#39;.
```

Profile model adds to JSON, but `profilePic` and `profileFields` return error about not matching and attribute. What Am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Just tried your setup, and it all works fine. I got back the combined JSON from all the serializers.

Comment: any ideas, why can I get "User" object has no attribute "profilePic"

Answer (score 0):

It is not recognizing profilePic on the user instance because it doesn't exist. If you try to do `user.profilePic` you'll get the same error.

You should be able to set the `related_name` on the `ProfilePic` model user ForeignKey so that user has a profilePic property and `user.profilePic` returns the user's profile pic.

```
class ProfilePic(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profilePic", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```